# How to say "mark the page that I reached"

Tags: usage, formulation-idiomatique

How to say in French

> I turned up the corner of the page to mark the page that I reached

Some ideas:

> J'ai corné la page pour marquer ou en suis-je
>   J'ai corné la page pour marquer d'où il me faut reprendre plus tard
>   J'ai corné la page pour marquer les pages que j'ai lues

Comment: All your ideas are valid interpretations, but the tense of the second clauses are a bit off, although everyone would understand what they mean. "J'ai corné la page pour marquer **où j'en étais**", "J'ai corné la page pour marquer d'où il me **faudrait** reprendre plus tard", "J'ai corné la page pour marquer les pages que **j'avais** lues".

Comment: I didn't notice I wrote my answer in french, please let me know if you want me to translate it, since I use to answer in english to english questions... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never heard "corné" before… (native French from Belgium)

Personally, I'd say:

> J'ai plié le coin de la page pour/afin d'indiquer où j'en étais arrivé. (or "de marquer")
>
> J'ai plié le coin de la page pour/afin d'indiquer à quelle page j'étais arrivé. (more literal)

Or something along these lines.

Comment: 'corné' do exist. I'm french, and even though I dislike how the word sounds (yeah that's petty) and prefer using 'plier le coin', one should use 'corner'...

Comment: As a native french, "plié le coin" sounds odd, whereas "corner une page" sounds very natural...

Answer (score 6):

> J'ai corné la page pour marquer **ou en suis-je**

"ou en suis-je" n'est pas correct, il faut dire "où j'en [suis/étais]"
Dire "où j'en étais" sous entend que vous vous êtes arrêté(e) de lire, on marque l’arrêt de l'action. 
Dire "où j'en suis" sous-entend que vous n'avez pas fini de lire le livre, donc que vous êtes encore dans l'histoire du livre. Ceci sera donc plus utilisé si vous êtes passionné(e) par cette lecture.
Les deux sont corrects.

---

> J'ai corné la page pour marquer **d'où il me faut reprendre plus tard**

La phrase est correcte, mais grammaticalement très lourde, une formulation plus légère pourrait être (merci [JeromeJ](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1894/jeromej)):

> J'ai corné la page pour marquer **où reprendre plus tard**

---

> J'ai corné la page pour marquer **les pages que j'ai lues**

La phrase est correcte, mais le sens n'est pas le même. On pourrait comprendre que vous avez corné CHAQUE page lue, et non uniquement la dernière.

---

**Conclusion**

La formulation la plus naturelle est donc la première, à savoir :

> J'ai corné la page pour marquer **où j'en [suis/étais]**

Comment: To correct "d'où il me faut reprendre plus tard", I think "pour marquer où reprendre plus tard" could be more acceptable.